# Invalid configuration i686-redhat-linux-gnu on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, qmail

I launch this command to build rpm package:

```
#>rpmbuild --rebuild -vv vqadmin-toaster-2.3.7-1.4.1.src.rpm
```

I'm on CentOs 6.4 and i want to build and install qmailtoaster packets.
Only this packet get an error:

**checking build system type... Invalid configuration 'i686-redhat-linux-gnu': machine 'i686-redhat-linux' not recognized**

What can i do? this is first time that i'm compiling RPM packages, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i also run into the same problem, according to qmailtoaster installation script the command suppose to be

```
 rpmbuild --rebuild --with cnt5064 vqadmin-toaster-2.3.7-1.4.1.src.rpm
```

built it has the same error msg as above

and I Google around and found out

[vqadmin build error](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.mail.qmail.toaster/36598)

> many of our programs are running automake versions that PREDATE 64-bit linux... and while most apps will build just fine (albeit less optimized), vqadmin 2.3.7 does NOT build successfully in this "unknown-linux" environment.

He offers a x86_64 rpm at the bottom